# how to find svn realm name for Jenkins build?

Tags: svn

I was building Jenkins job with my cerdentials, but lately, it has stopped working. I found that I need to supply "Additional Credentials" as:
[image]

How do I find "realm"?. I am assuming i need to issue SVN command to do so(I have win7 Jenkins machine), but have no idea what is it?
  Can someone explain in simple terms what this does?
  Thanks
  sedy

Answer (score 2):

Following works;

```
svn --no-auth-cache --config-dir invalid info [SVN URL]
```

Above will lead to result where you need to enter your password 
and read "Authenticiation Realm".

sedy

Comment: This did not work for me. I used that command, and it returns a load of info, including Revision, Repository Root etc, but no realm.  I have yet to find a way to find a realm, and, once its found, to find out what to actually enter into the Realm box on the extra credentials.

Comment: Mine returned `Authentication realm: <svn://server-name:3690> baed1b1b-4b5a-fa3b-a583-fff81ffdab1d` and I think the string I have to enter for the realm is `<svn://server-name:3690>`.  I shall test it out and if it fails I will post here again.

Comment: I am still seeing messages in my polling log like: `org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Authentication required for 'baed0b0b-4a5a-fa4b-a583-fff81f9dab1d'` so the work aroudn of adding the `<svn://server-name:3690>` does not seem to have helped.  I wonder if I need that sha too?

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue here and after some searching I found the following:

We are using **visual svn server** (windows implementation of svn server). When we use the command specified by jenkins (and in this question), we also didn't get that realm info. So after logging in with rdp on the visual svn server, I checked the C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\conf\httpd.conf

There I found the following setting:

```
AuthName "VisualSVN Server"
```

So when I transformed the format

```
<proto://server:port> SvnRealmName
```

into this:

```
<https://pathtomyserver.com:443> VisualSVN Server
```

it started working, hopefully it will help someone else ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this question has been posted but here is where you can find the realm name :

Go to the following directory and open up one of the files inside using Notepad++ or sth. Two lines below the "svn:realmstring" expression , you can see the realm name.

```
~\.Subversion\auth\svn.ssl.server
```